# Eslint error handling react/prop-types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm using the Airbnb javascript standards to lint my react app and i'm getting an error i'm not sure how to fix. This is my first file in my application and all the other components will follow after this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class RootPage extends Component {
render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
}

RootPage.prototype={
    children: PropTypes.node
}
```

My **this.props.children** is throwing eslint error **'children' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)**

I have no idea how to fix it, any help is much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in `propTypes` (you have now `prototype`), try with:

```
RootPage.propTypes={
    children: PropTypes.node
}
```

Comment: @spidy, if it worked, could you please mark your question as answered?